# Business Interface pattern with EJB with Remote as well as local interfaces

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

How can I use Business Interface pattern with an EJB (session bean) with Local as well remote interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter whether the interface is local or remote. You can write all your business methods into one interface and then use it as local and remote interface. The difference is how it will get called, but not what is executed.